# Dynamic query variable error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `#months` as below

```
MONTH_ID    FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH   MIN_DATE    MAX_DATE
1               FSA201510       20151001    20151031
2               FSA201511       20151101    20151130
3               FSA201512       20151201    20151204
```

I am using below dynamic query to update a column `SCCount` in table `mastercount`(has 3 rows)-

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000), @fym varchar(6)

DECLARE @I INT, @ROWS INT

SET @ROWS=(SELECT count(*) from #MONTHS)      
SET @I=1    

WHILE @I<=@ROWS          
BEGIN
    SET @fym=(SELECT RIGHT(FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,6) from #MONTHS where month_id=@I)

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE mastercount'
    SET @sql += ' SET SCCount = (SELECT count(*) from '
    SET @sql += ' dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' + cast(@fym as varchar(6))+ ') WHERE row=@I'

    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @I=@I+1
END
```

This gives an error `Must declare the scalar variable "@I".`
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this

```
 SET @sql += ' dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' + cast(@fym as varchar(6))+ ') WHERE row=@I'
```

to this

```
 SET @sql += ' dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' + cast(@fym as varchar(6))+ ') WHERE row=' + CAST(@I AS NVARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: Smart answer. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `@I` is not recognized by your dynamic query. You should parameterized `@I` instead and use `sp_executesql` to run your query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(8000), @fym VARCHAR(6)

DECLARE @I INT, @ROWS INT

SET @ROWS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MONTHS)      
SET @I = 1    

WHILE @I <= @ROWS          
BEGIN
    SET @fym = (SELECT RIGHT(FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,6) FROM #MONTHS WHERE month_id = @I)

    SET @sql = N'UPDATE mastercount'
    SET @sql += N' SET SCCount = (SELECT count(*) from '
    SET @sql += N' dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' + cast(@fym as varchar(6))+ N') WHERE row=@I'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@I INT', @I

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

Comment: Excellent solution. But do you still need to have EXEC(@sql) statement ?